# Python: How to decompress a GZIP file to an uncompressed file on disk?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gzip

I want to emulate the behavior of `gzip -d <file.gz>` within a Python script.

The compressed GZIP file is decompressed and written as a file with the same file name as the original GZIP file without the .gz extension.

file.abc.gz --> file.abc

It's not obvious how to do this using the gzip library, all the examples in the docs are for compressing data arrays, and I've not yet found a good example from research.

### Edit

I've tried the below using tarfile module, but unfortunately it's not working, I think since the GZIP file wasn't created with tar.

```
# get the zipped file's contents list, extract the file
with tarfile.TarFile(local_zipped_filename) as tar_file:

    # list the contents, make sure we only extract the expected named file
    members = tar_file.getmembers()
    for member in members:
        if member.name == filename_unzipped:
            members_to_extract = [member]
            tar_file.extractall(path=destination_dir, members=members_to_extract)
            break   # we've extracted our file, done
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
import gzip, shutil

with gzip.open('file.abc.gz', 'r') as f_in, open('file.abc', 'wb') as f_out:
  shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
```

The [`gzip` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html) provides a file-like object with the decompressed content of a gzip file; the [`shutil` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html) provides a convenient helper for copying content from one file-like object to another.

---

This is a simple inversion of an example given in [the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#examples-of-usage):

> Example of how to GZIP compress an existing file:
>
> ```
> import gzip
> import shutil
> with open('/home/joe/file.txt', 'rb') as f_in:
>     with gzip.open('/home/joe/file.txt.gz', 'wb') as f_out:
>         shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
> ```

Comment: Very helpful answer, this appears to work as advertised. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

You can use the **[tarfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html)** module to what you are asking.

**Example:**

```
import tarfile
tar = tarfile.open("test.tar.gz")
tar.extractall()
tar.close()
```

Comment: Only true if the OP's file is actually in `.tar.gz` format, which they haven't as yet specified.

Comment: Seems to be the case, I get an error when I try using this approach: tarfile.ReadError: invalid header..