# Downloading csv files from a URL - trying to add file extensions before calling urlretrieve is causing pandas to raise BadZipFile

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to download multiple .csv files from a URL where the only variable is the year that needs adding to the end of the constant URL string. I noticed that when I download manually from the [website in question](https://environment.data.gov.uk/water-quality/view/download) the .csv file extension is added automatically and there have been no issues using it with `pandas`. However, I would like a `def` function that can automate this downloading process and I would prefer to have .zip (or .gzip for Linux, which I have already created a method for changing the extension) files due to the size of them (20+GB total across all 23 files).

However my issue is that at the moment I am putting the save directory (`year_save_dir`) with `.csv.zip` added at the end as otherwise, there is no extension on the downloaded file (and it is significantly smaller so I am assuming it is meant to be a .zip file). When I try to read the file using `pandas` with the `.csv.zip` file extension it returns this error:

```
   File "C:\Python37\lib\zipfile.py", line 1325, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

I understand why there is an error, but I am unsure how to fix it. If I download the files with no added extension in `year_save_dir =` it looks like this:

[image]

With `.csv.zip` it appears like this:

[image]

With the contents of this `.csv.zip` looking like (true size of ~1.75GB, reading this with `pandas` returns the above error):

[image]

When I add just `.zip` it compresses fine but then returns just a file with no extensions:

[image]

How can I download the files with compressed extensions (`.zip` in this case) but also add the needed `.csv` extension to the file, is this possible or is there a better solution/method available? I am using Python 3.7 if that makes a difference.

****Code**:**

```
import os
import urllib.request as ureq

import pandas as pd


EA_URL = ('https://environment.data.gov.uk/water-quality/batch/' +
                  'measurement?year=')

DEFAULT_YEARS = [x for x in range(2000, 2002)]


def csv_download(save_dir: str, years: list = DEFAULT_YEARS) -> None:
    for year in years:
        year = str(year)
        print("Started year {}".format(year))
        # Changing the below line is what is causing issues
        year_save_dir = save_dir + year + '.csv.zip'
        env_url = EA_URL + year
        ureq.urlretrieve(env_url, year_save_dir)
    return


def pandas_breaks(save_dir):
    # This function fails
    for file in os.listdir(save_dir):
        df = pd.read_csv(save_dir + file)


def main():
    save_dir = 'C:/Users/Acer/Downloads/Testing/'
    if not os.path.isdir(save_dir):
        os.makedirs(save_dir)
    csv_download(save_dir)
    pandas_breaks(save_dir)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Edit:** I have experimented with an answer to [How can I replace (or strip) an extension from a filename in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56807917/19520503) but this actually removes the .csv from the zipped file too (when replacing `.csv.zip` with just `.zip`) so it appears that the .csv is essential in the file extension. It is not attached to the actual downloaded file unless it is also in zipped file name (.csv.zip). I got the message return from `urlretrieve` and it gives this:

```
x-amz-id-2: vUOH963SZ6x+NBjj02vFIFmpgzBPfxhIvZLSE+qcKcfeJzlfFwZQdq8OvWgazQeXrupowH9OxtI=
x-amz-request-id: YE1P1QBQMXGK6E9J
Date: Tue, 13 Sep 2022 18:21:35 GMT
Last-Modified: Tue, 13 Sep 2022 05:03:18 GMT
ETag: "74e84c081cb7fbe5fc0ad4850fc38d51-7"
Content-Encoding: gzip
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: text/csv
Server: AmazonS3
Content-Length: 57932207
Connection: close
```

So it appears to be a `.gzip` extension. I have no idea why when I download it from the website, it downloads correctly as a .csv file but when using Python, it comes with no extension and compressed. Does this extra information help at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The edit appears to have given away how to successfully download the .csv's without corruption and then unzip. The answer to [How to decompress a GZIP file to an uncompressed file on disk? by Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48466691/19520503) was used to create a function that could turn the .gzip files into uncompressed .csv's, the edit to the question showing `Content-Encoding: gzip` was key as the module `zipfile` was not working.

The output looks like this now and matches the sizes of the downloaded .csv files in another folder:

[image]

More testing is required to compare the downloaded files against the manually downloaded files to ensure the method is not corrupting/changing data but this is a solution. The working code:

```
import os
import gzip
import shutil
import urllib.request as ureq

import pandas as pd


EA_URL = ('https://environment.data.gov.uk/water-quality/batch/' +
                  'measurement?year=')

DEFAULT_YEARS = [x for x in range(2000, 2002)]


def csv_download(save_dir: str, years: list = DEFAULT_YEARS) -> None:
    for year in years:
        year = str(year)
        print("Started year {}".format(year))
        gzip_save_dir = save_dir + year + '.gzip'
        csv_save_dir = save_dir + year + '.csv'
        env_url = EA_URL + year
        _, message = ureq.urlretrieve(env_url, gzip_save_dir)
        print("Started decompressing year {}".format(year))
        gzip_decompress(gzip_save_dir, csv_save_dir)
    pandas_breaks(save_dir)
    return


def pandas_breaks(save_dir):
    for file in os.listdir(save_dir):
        if file.endswith('.csv'):
            df = pd.read_csv(save_dir + file, nrows=10)
            print(df)


def gzip_decompress(gzip_name, csv_name):
    with gzip.open(gzip_name, 'r') as f_in, open(csv_name, 'wb') as f_out:
        shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)


def main():
    save_dir = 'C:/Users/Acer/Downloads/Testing/'
    if not os.path.isdir(save_dir):
        os.makedirs(save_dir)
    csv_download(save_dir)
    pandas_breaks(save_dir)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I won't accept this answer for a few days in case anyone has any better solutions.